# WPF custom Control with custom drawing and ActualWidth

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls, drawingcontext, actualwidth

I'm trying to create a custom control (deriving from **Control**) with its own drawing logic. The control is simply drawing a diagonal line from the upper-left corner to the right-bottom corner of the control. This logic is based on the control's **ActualWidth** and **ActualHeight**, which are only available when rendering the control (AFAIK).

My question is, *what is the proper way to do custom drawing efficiently?*

There's not much documentation on this, and I'm afraid I'm doing something stupid or unnecessary, like forcing refreshes/redraws every time OnPropertyChanged is fired...

Here is the control's template:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
          <Canvas>
            <Line x:Name="PART_Diagonal"
                  Y1="{Binding Path=DiagonalTop}"
                  Y2="{Binding Path=DiagonalBottom}"
                  X1="{Binding Path=DiagonalLeft}"
                  X2="{Binding Path=DiagonalRight}"
                  Stroke="Red" />
          </Canvas>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

And here is the logic:

```cs
public class MyCustomControl : Control, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  static MyCustomControl()
  {
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata( typeof( MyCustomControl ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( typeof( MyCustomControl ) ) );
  }

  public MyCustomControl()
  {
    DataContext = this;
  }

  protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged( SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo )
  {
    base.OnRenderSizeChanged( sizeInfo );

    var margin = 25d;

// These calculations are based on the control's current size.
    DiagonalTop = margin;
    DiagonalBottom = ActualHeight - margin;
    DiagonalLeft = margin;
    DiagonalRight = ActualWidth - margin;

// Is this forcing redraws (i.e. invalidating the layout)?
    OnPropertyChanged( "DiagonalTop" );
    OnPropertyChanged( "DiagonalBottom" );
    OnPropertyChanged( "DiagonalLeft" );
    OnPropertyChanged( "DiagonalRight" );
  }

  public double DiagonalTop { get; private set; }
  public double DiagonalBottom{ get; private set; }
  public double DiagonalLeft { get; private set; }
  public double DiagonalRight { get; private set; }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
  {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
      PropertyChanged.Invoke( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyname ) );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it much easier, without any additional properties. Simply use the [Padding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.padding) property for the inner spacing:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
        <Canvas Name="DrawingCanvas">
            <Line X1="0" X2="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DrawingCanvas}" 
                  Y1="0" Y2="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DrawingCanvas}" 
                  Stroke="Red" />
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Use your control with Padding:

```
<local:MyCustomControl Padding="25" ... />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It IS a good suggestion, but doesn't really give me the answer I want. I'm more interested in knowing how to properly use **OnRenderSizeChanged** and updating properties that other elements bind to.

Comment: Ok, then you could improve performance by replacing the four calls to OnPropertyChanged, each with a property name argument, by a single call to OnPropertyChanged with a null argument or an empty string. This would notify that all properties have changed at once.